# Binding Date of DateTime in a control

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Text="{Binding Path=PostDate.Date}"
```

I don't want to show the time part in my control. 
Instead of 8/26/2010 12:00 AM, I want 8/26/2010.

Is there any easy way to do that without any explicit/implicit conversion or overriding some methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3.5 SP1, you can use Binding.StringFormat. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) for more examples

```
Text="{Binding Path=PostData.Data, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}"
```