# <asp:ControlParamenter /> and nonstandard (en-US) DateTime binding

Tags: asp.net, datetime, culture

Database date format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
C# default date output: "MM/dd/yyyy"
**My date format**: "dd/MM/yyyy"

How do I use the **asp:SqlDataSource** with an **asp:ControlParameter** connected to an **asp:TextBox** using **my date format**? Specifically, I wanted to know

1. if there was a way to do this without having it done in code-behind
2. if I'm bound to code-behind, how to do it?

I've read about the Culture class, but I'm not sure that's the right path to explore. I've also had a check on some stackoverflow posts and came accross this [Binding Date of DateTime in a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572364/binding-date-of-datetime-in-a-control), but I've never seen this structure of Text formatting before in ASP.NET.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it seems the example in the linked post goes only for WPF.